# Powers modulo a number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Say one knows $a^{i}\mod A$ for all $i\in\{1,2,3,\dots,N\}$. What is the minimum $N$ needed to get $a$ assuming $a<A^2$?

Comment: Hmm I think no $N$ suffices. Take $a=17$, $A=5$. Any $(a+kA)^i$ for $k\in\Bbb N$ has the same residues modulo $A$ for every $i\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: You are right for all $A\lt a \lt A^2$...

Comment: But knowing $a^1$ suffices to know the "base class" of $a\pmod A$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $a \equiv b \pmod A$, we will have $a^i \equiv b^i \pmod A$ for all $i$.  Thus, while you will be able to determine the residue of $a \pmod A$, you would not generally be able to determine its true value.